# How to display mysql data on html page in node js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I am using `node express` to connect to `Mysql`  and i am able to write fetch query from `mysql` but results  come in console in the form of array , i am a beginner to the Node.js , please  help me on how i can display the  results from mysql to `HTML template` .

See what i have :

config.js :

```
   ....

           var express = require('express');
           var mysql = require('mysql');         
        //  get connect to mysql database
               var app = express();                      // http connection
               var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  // Handle to get interface form data

          var flash = require('connect-flash');   // enable the use of flash message 
          var session = require('express-session');
          var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
          var validator = require('express-validator');

     // Create routes of folder which contain libraries and functions

        var router = express.Router();
        var path    = __dirname + '/views/';
     // Create routes 

      router.use(function (req,res,next) {
      console.log("/" + req.method);
        next();
      });

    router.get("/",function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
      }); 
 app.use("/",router);

     // Fetch display books from mysql to home page 

       connection.query("SELECT * FROM books_store", function (err, result, fields) {
         if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
       });

  app.listen(1000, function () {
     console.log('app is listening on port 1000!');
     console.log('run "localhost:1000" in your browser!');
      });

 ....
```

Html code :

index.html   (I need results to be as follow but i don't know how to do it )  :

```
  ....

  @for(results){
    <div class="post-header font-alt">
     <div class="post-meta">&nbsp;<p>@results.Bookname</p></div>
              </div>
     <div class='caption'>
    <p><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span>@results.price</p>
</div>       
   <div class="fa fa-bar-chart"><p>@results.quantity</p></div>
  }
....
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-template this templating engine (if you planned to use it as you seemed to mention) doesn't allow much features, as loop / forEach, etc... You should use a templating/view engine a bit more elaborate. I've used ejs once, you can see an example there if you want : https://github.com/sztan/todoList/

Comment: please format your code first. Then, please refer to some materials on how to use `mysql` and `express` library for example: https://www.codementor.io/codeforgeek/node-js-mysql-8b5nh45r9

Comment: @thisDonkey, thanks but your response doesn't seem to solve my issues 'cause yours doesn't use mysql